# Updating existing event in calendar with post variables

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm stuck with a form that is supposed to be able to update the information of an existing event in a calendar. When transferring data via the form from my event.php page to my event_updated.php page I haven't been able to make it recognize which event it was sent from. The event_updated.php page is supposed to recognize this, update the event in the database and then return to the event.php page with the new information.

This is the form on event.php. The $id-variable is the GET-variable used to recognize the event on this page:

```
<form action="event_updated.php" method="post">
    <p>Change name: <input type="text" name="event_name" value="'; if(isset($_POST['event_name'])) echo $_POST['event_name']; echo '" /><br />
    New location: <input type="text" name="location" value="'; if(isset($_POST['location'])) echo $_POST['location']; echo '" /><br />
    Starting (ex: 2013-05-01 18:00:00): <input type="text" name="starttime" value="'; if(isset($_POST['starttime'])) echo $_POST['starttime']; echo '" /><br />
    Ending (ex: 2013-05-01 18:30:00): <input type="text" name="endtime" value="'; if(isset($_POST['endtime'])) echo $_POST['endtime']; echo '" /></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Update event" />
    <input type="hidden" name="this_event" value="'; $_POST['$id']; echo '" />
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
</form>
```

This is the code from event_updated.php:

```
<?php
$page_title = "The event has been updated";

include ('../includes/topnavigation.php');
require_once ('../mysqli_connect.php');

session_start(); // Start session

// If no session value is set then they are redirected to index.php
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    require_once ('../includes/login_functions.inc.php');
    $url = absolute_url();
    header("Location: $url");
    exit(); // Exit script
}

require_once ('../mysqli_connect.php'); // Connect to DB


    //Check if the form has been submitted
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {

    $errors = array(); //Initialize an error array

    // Check for event name
    if (empty($_POST['event_name'])) {
        $errors[] = 'You have not given your event a name.';
    } else {
        $en = trim($_POST['event_name']);
    }
    // Check for event name
    if (empty($_POST['this_event'])) {
        $errors[] = 'this_event not transferred correctly.';
    } else {
        $en = trim($_POST['this_event']);
    }
    // Check for event location
    if (empty($_POST['location'])) {
        $errors[] = 'You have not determined where the meeting is taking place.';
    } else {
        $l = trim($_POST['location']);
    }

    if (empty($_POST['starttime'])) {
        $errors[] = 'You have not determined when the meeting is starting.';
    } else {
        $s = trim($_POST['starttime']);

        $s = strtotime($s);
        $s = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$s);
    }
    if (empty($_POST['endtime'])) {
        $errors[] = 'You have not determined when the meeting is ending.';
    } 
    else {
        $e = trim($_POST['endtime']);

        $e = strtotime($e);
        $e = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$e);
    }

    if (empty($errors)) { // If everything is ok

        // Create the event in the database
        require_once('../mysqli_connect.php'); // DB connect
        $tbl_name="events";

        $sql="UPDATE events SET creator_id='{$_SESSION['user_id']}',event_name=event_name, ,endtime=endtime,starttime=starttime,duration=duration,location=location WHERE this_event=event_id";
        $result= @mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);

        if($result){
            // retrieve event from database
            $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
            echo $user_id;
            $event = "SELECT * FROM events e WHERE e.creator_id = {$_SESSION['user_id']} AND e.event_name = '$en'";
            $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $event); // Run the query

            if ($r) {
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                $event_id = $row['event_id'];
                echo $event_id;
                header("Location: event.php?id=$event_id"); // $row['event_name']               
            } else {
                echo mysqli_error($dbc);
            } 

            echo "Succesfull";
            echo "<BR>";
            echo "<a href='newevent.php'>Back to main page</a>";
        } else {
            echo mysqli_error($dbc);
            echo "ERROR";
            echo $result;
            echo '<h2>Error!</h2>
            <p class="error">The following error(s) occured:<br />';
            foreach ($errors as $msg) { // Print each error
                echo " - $msg<br />\n";
            }
        }
        mysqli_close($dbc);
    }
    else {
        echo '<h2>Error!!!</h2>
            <p class="error">The following error(s) occured:<br />';
        foreach ($errors as $msg) { // Print each error
            echo " - $msg<br />\n";
        }
    }               
}               
?>
```

The entire code for event.php:

```
<?php

$page_title = 'View event';

include ('../includes/topnavigation.php');

session_start(); // Start session

// If no session value is set then they are redirected to index.php
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    require_once ('../includes/login_functions.inc.php');
    $url = absolute_url();
    header("Location: $url");
    exit(); // Exit script
}

$id = $_GET['id'];
$loggedin = $_SESSION['user_id'];

require_once ('../mysqli_connect.php'); // Connect to DB

$event = "SELECT * FROM events e, users u WHERE u.user_id = e.creator_id AND e.event_id = $id";

$participants = "SELECT u.first_name, u.last_name FROM users u WHERE u.user_id IN (SELECT user FROM participants WHERE event = $id)";

$creator = "SELECT creator_id FROM events";

$add = "SELECT user_id as UserID, CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS Name FROM users ORDER BY reg_date DESC";

$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $event); // Run the query

if ($r) { // If OK, display event

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

// Table with event info

echo '<h2>Event: ' . $row['event_name'] . '</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top">
                <table align="left" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">Date:</td><td align="left">' . $row['date'] . '</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">Start:</td><td align="left">' . $row['starttime'] . '</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">Duration:</td><td align="left">' . $row['duration'] . '</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">Location:</td><td align="left">' . $row['location'] . '</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">Creator:</td><td align="left"><a href="usermeetings.php?id='. $row['creator_id'] . '">' .      $row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['last_name']  . '</a></td>
                    </tr>';
                }

                mysqli_free_result ($r); // Free up the ressources

            } else {  // If failure

                echo '<p class="error">Event info could not be retrieved. We apologize for any inconveniences.</p>';

                // Debugging message:

                echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '<br /><br />Query: ' . $event . '</p>';

            } // End of IF

            $r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $participants); // Run the query

            if ($r) { // If OK, display event

                echo '
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">All participants:</td>
                        <td align="left">';
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                            echo $row['first_name'] . ' ' . $row['last_name'] . '<br />';
                        }

                        mysqli_free_result ($r); // Free up the ressources

                    } else {  // If failure

                        echo '<p class="error">Could not retrieve list of attending users. We apologize for any inconveniences.</p>';

                        // Debugging message:

                        echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '<br /><br />Query: ' . $participants . '</p>';

                    } // End of IF

                    echo '
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>'; // Table is closed
            echo '</td>
                 <td align="left" valign="top">';

$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $add);

if ($r) {

// Table header

    echo '<h3>You have created this event</h3>
    <p>Add participants, update info or simply delete it: <a href="deleteevent.php?id=' . $id .'">DELETE</a></p>

    <p><b>Update event</b></p>

    <form action="event_updated.php" method="post">
        <p>Change name: <input type="text" name="event_name" value="'; if(isset($_POST['event_name'])) echo $_POST['event_name']; echo '" /><br />
        New location: <input type="text" name="location" value="'; if(isset($_POST['location'])) echo $_POST['location']; echo '" /><br />
        Starting (ex: 2013-05-01 18:00:00): <input type="text" name="starttime" value="'; if(isset($_POST['starttime'])) echo $_POST['starttime']; echo '" /><br />
        Ending (ex: 2013-05-01 18:30:00): <input type="text" name="endtime" value="'; if(isset($_POST['endtime'])) echo $_POST['endtime']; echo '" /></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Update event" />
        <input type="hidden" name="this_event" value="'; if(isset($_POST['$id'])) echo $_POST['this_event']; echo '" />
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
    </form>

    <table align="left" cellspacing="3" cellpading="3">

        <tr>
            <td align="left"><b>Add participants</b></td>
        </tr>
            ';

        // Fetch and print records:

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            echo '<tr>
                <td align="left"><a href="usermeetings.php?id='. $row['UserID'] . '">' . $row['Name'] . '</td>
            <td align="left"><a href="addparticipant.php?add='. $row['UserID'] . '&id=' . $id .'">ADD</a></td>
            </tr>
            ';

        }

        echo '</table>'; // Table is closed

        mysqli_free_result ($r); // Free up the ressources

    } else {  // If failure

        echo '<br clear="all" /><p class="error">The user list could not be retrieved. We apologize for any inconveniences.</p>';

        // Debugging message:

        echo '<p>' . mysqli_error($dbc) . '<br /><br />Query: ' . $add . '</p>';
    }
    echo '</td>
    </tr>
</table>';

mysqli_close($dbc); // closes DB connection

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" value="Update event" name="submit"/>
```

and

```
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
```

should be

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

EDIT 1: and also

```
<form action="event_updated.php" method="post">
    <p>Change name: <input type="text" name="event_name" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['event_name'])) echo $_POST['event_name'];?>" /><br />
    New location: <input type="text" name="location" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['location'])) echo $_POST['location'];?>" /><br />
    Starting (ex: 2013-05-01 18:00:00): <input type="text" name="starttime" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['starttime'])) echo $_POST['starttime'];?>" /><br />
    Ending (ex: 2013-05-01 18:30:00): <input type="text" name="endtime" value="<?php  if(isset($_POST['endtime'])) echo $_POST['endtime'];?>" /></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Update event" />
    <input type="hidden" name="this_event" value="<?php echo $_POST['$id'];>?" />
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
</form>
```

Comment: This solution returns no errors on event_updated.php, but it still doesn't update the information in the database or redirect back to the event.php-page.

Comment: what do you mean of such this things `value="'; $_POST['$id']; echo '"` ?

Comment: The event.php displays the event from this GET-variable that it gets from the URL. For example like this event.php?id=1. I wan't this information to be transferred with the form, so that the event_updated.php page knows that it is this event it is supposed to update in the database.

Comment: i mean there is syntax error. it should be like this `value="<?php echo $_POST['$id'];?>"`?

Comment: The form is already placed within php-tags. I've updated the main post above with the entire code for event.php.

Answer (score 0):

First, your mixing up when your post data is available. You already have the $id of the event, simply set that directly as the this_event value in the form:

```
<form action="event_updated.php" method="post">
....
    <input type="hidden" name="this_event" value="$id" />
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
</form>
```

Now the this_event should be set. But you are overwriting the $en variable from event_name:

```
if (empty($_POST['this_event'])) {
    $errors[] = 'this_event not transferred correctly.';
} else {
    $en = trim($_POST['this_event']);
}
```

put the `event_id` in a separate variable:

```
if (empty($_POST['this_event'])) {
    $errors[] = 'this_event not transferred correctly.';
} else {
    $this_event = trim($_POST['this_event']);
}
```

Finally, and you are going to kick yourself, you are not using any of the variables in your database update, which is the reason it fails every time:

```
$sql="UPDATE events SET creator_id='{$_SESSION['user_id']}',event_name=event_name, ,endtime=endtime,starttime=starttime,duration=duration,location=location WHERE this_event=event_id";
$result= @mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
```

Should be:

```
$sql="UPDATE events SET creator_id='{$_SESSION['user_id']}',event_name=$event_name, ,endtime=$endtime,starttime=$starttime,duration=$duration,location=$location WHERE event_id=$this_event";
$result= @mysqli_query($dbc, $sql);
```

Good luck!

EDIT: Your redirect from event_updated.php to event.php is not the event_id:

```
header("Location: event.php?id=$event_id"); // $row['event_name']
```

Should be:

```
header("Location: event.php?id=$this_event");
```